# Android Studio not opening NOT issue with JAVA_HOME variable

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I try to open Android Studio on Windows 7 32-bit, the program doesn't open.  I receive a message confirming that I want to open the studio.exe file, so I know I clicked the file.  This is NOT an issue with the JAVA_HOME environment variable not being set correctly.  The variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161, the location of the JDK, which I have checked multiple times.  This problem happens with Android Studio 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 3.0.1.

I discovered this problem after I had been using version 2.3.3 for a while.  This had been an intermittent problem before which was usually solved by waiting a bit and reopening it.  However, this problem has been going on for several days now.  The only thing that I know of that was changed about the time the error occurred was that I changed the VM options to -Xmx2048m and -Xms2048m.  However, I don't think this would have any effect.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio (first with 3.0.1 than with 2.3.2).  I originally had the JRE and it worked fine without the JAVA_HOME variable.  I have tried setting a JRE_HOME, JAVA_HOME, and JDK_HOME (not at the same time) variable with a path to the JRE and the JDK.

One weird thing that happened was when I first reinstalled Android Studio (3.0.1), the first time I tried to open Android Studio it worked.  The program opened, but after attempting a Gradle sync it displayed this error message:

Error: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized JVM option is used.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

In the past, I was able to fix that error by closing some other programs that were running and reopening the program.  However, this time when tried to reopen the program nothing happened.

Comment: *Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB* looks like you're out of disk space or memory, It is trying to reserve ~1GB of it

Comment: @Jon Right, I had been able to fix that error before by closing some other programs that I had running and relaunching Android Studio.  However, after closing Android Studio and some other programs, I was unable to get Android Studio to reopen.  That is my current problem.

Comment: How much memory is on your machine?

Comment: @Jon 4 GB (3.44 GB usable)

Comment: How much available memory does task manager show?

Comment: @Jon just over 1GB, but I have some other programs running right now which were closed when I tried to open Android Studio.